# Proving the local invertibilty of a locally open map in the light of inverse function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by $$f\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right)=\left(e^{x_2} \cos x_1, e^{x_2} \sin x_1, 2 x_1-\cos x_3\right).$$ Consider the set $$E=\left\{\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3\right.~\text{: there exists an open subset}~U~\text{around}~\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right)~\text{such that}~ \left.f\right|_U~\text{is an open map}\}.$$ Then which of the following is/are true?

1. $E=\mathbb{R}^3$
2. $E$ is countable
3. $E$ is not countable but not $\mathbb{R}^3$
4. $\left\{\left(x_1, x_2, \frac{\pi}{2}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ is a proper subset of $E$.

I realize that $f$ is locally invertible on the set $$F=\{\Bbb x=(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \Bbb R^3 :~\text{the determinant of the Jacobian matrix}~Df(\Bbb x)~\text{is non zero}\}$$
$$=\Bbb R^3-\{(x_1,x_2,n \pi) \in \Bbb R^3~:~n \in \Bbb Z\},$$
in the light of inverse function theorem and [invariance of the domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). Thus, we have $F \subseteq E$, but how can I make $E=F$?

i.e, I need to say the open map $\left.f\right|_U$ (mentioned in the definition of $E$) is injective as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuously differentiable  (and the determinant is continuous), the set $\{det Df(x) \neq 0\}$ is an open set. The set $F$  for which you claim that it is the same set is not open, however.

Comment: @Thomas I've corrected the mistake pointed out by you, Thanks, and, how can we justify the claim 'the set $\{\Bbb x \in \Bbb R^3~:~\det Df(\Bbb x) \neq 0\}$ is an open set for a function $f \in C^1(\Bbb R^3)$' ?

Comment: For continuous maps, the preimage of an open set is open. Since the set $\{x\neq 0\}$ is open, so is it's preimage under the continuous map $det Df(x)$.

Comment: @Thomas Fine, can we use this fact to prove $E=F$ here?